# Xamarin forms splash screen with lottie animation

Tags: xamarin.forms, lottie

Is it possible to have a lottie animation when the splash screen is launched?

any examples out there on xamarin?

thanks

Comment: There are many examples:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9b2IFQvkTOg

https://github.com/07JP27/lottie-splash

Many many more, google is your friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's impossible on iOS. The launch screen on iOS only accepts the static image and we can't add any code behind to adjust its display.

If you want to implement it on Xamarin. I recommend you to use a splash page as the App's MainPage first. Place your animation there. Then change the App's MainPage to your first page after the animation has finished.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible, because there is no code-behind available.

Workaround would be to place a screen after the splash screen and add your Lottie animation there. This way you can also control how long you want to show the (fake) splashscreen.